# Finding the function$g(x)$ which $f(x)=g(x), x\geq 0$

Tags: calculus

I found this question interesting:

> Which one of the following functions are equal to $f(x)=\lfloor \sqrt{x}-\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor\rfloor$? ($\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function)
>
> 1. $g(x)=\sqrt{x-|x|}$
> 2. $g(x)=\sqrt{-x+|x|}$
> 3. $g(x)=\sqrt{x+|x|}$
> 4. $g(x)=\sqrt{-x-|x|}$

What I have done is to examine the domains of above functions regarding the fact that $0\leq x-\lfloor x\rfloor<1$. Just to share your ideas about this Maths multiple choices. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think that $f(x)$ is the floor function of the decimal part of $\sqrt{x}$ so it is identically zero in for all $x\geq 0$. Which of the functions $g(x)$ is identically zero for all $x\geq 0$?

Comment: Honestly, I did the same way but I thought maybe another approach was there to see what we reached to. Thanks.

Comment: (+1): That isn't quite enough on its own, as it leaves two options. Only one of them shares the same domain of definition, though.